# Change of variables, application of area and coarea formula

Tags: calculus, lebesgue-integral, geometric-measure-theory

I have a question about an application of area and coarea formula and change of variables.

Let $D$ be a bounded and connected open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$ with $C^{1}$-boundary. Define $D_{\epsilon}=\{x \in \bar{D}:d(x,\partial D)\leq \epsilon \}$. **I want to show the following equation holds:**

\begin{equation} \int_{D_{\epsilon}}\exp
\left(-|x-y|^{2}\right)\,dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\exp\left(-r^{2}\right)d\left\{ m(D_{\epsilon}\cap B(x,r))\right\}\cdots(1),
\end{equation}

equivalently (by integration by parts formula),
\begin{equation}
\int_{D_{\epsilon}}\exp \left(-|x-y|^{2}\right)\,dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}2r\exp\left(-r^{2}\right) m(D_{\epsilon}\cap B(x,r))\,dr,
\end{equation}
where $B(x,r)$ and $m$ denote the open Ball of radius $r$ centerd at $x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}$ and $d$-dim Lebesgue measure, respectively. $d\left\{ m(D_{\epsilon}\cap B(x,r))\right\}$ is the Lebesgue stieltjes measure generated by the function $r \mapsto m(D_{\epsilon} \cap B(x,r))$ on $(0,\infty)$.

**My attempt**

Let $f$ be a $\mathbb{R}$-valued integrable function on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$. Note that the following equations hold:
\begin{equation} 
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}f\,dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}
\frac{d}{dr} \left(\int_{B(0,r)} f\,dx \right)\,dr,\quad
\frac{d}{dr}\int_{B(0,r)}f\,dx= \int_{\partial B(0,r)}f\,d\sigma,
\end{equation}
where $\sigma$ is the $(d-1)$ dim Hausdorff measure (surface measure). Using these equations, we have
\begin{align}
\int_{D_{\epsilon}}\exp \left(-|x-y|^{2}\right)\,dy&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{d}{dr}\left( \int_{ B(0,r)}1_{D_{\epsilon}}(y)\exp\left(-|x-y|^{2} \right)\,dy\right)\,dr \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\partial B(0,r)} 1_{D_{\epsilon}}(y) \exp\left(-|x-y|^{2} \right)\,d \sigma\,dr \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{\partial B(0,r) \cap D_{\epsilon}}  \exp\left(-|x-y|^{2} \right)\,d \sigma\,dr
\end{align}
But I couldn't show
\begin{equation}
\exp\left(-r^{2}\right)d\left\{ m(D_{\epsilon}\cap B(x,r))\right\}=\int_{\partial B(0,r) \cap D_{\epsilon}} \exp\left(-|x-y|^{2} \right)\,d \sigma\,dr.
\end{equation}
If you know how to show the equation $(1)$, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.